# WCF works ONLY Asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, client, asp.net-ajax

I have a WCF “MWManageSession” service inside my WebApplication so I don’t have any service reference.
The problem is that seems to work  only asynchronously instead of synchronously.

public interface IMWManageSession{

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string SetIdSelezionato_SessionData(String[] pvalori, SessionNavigation pSN, long varpChangingAzienda);
```

}

I consume the wcf on a client function using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: jsonText,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        ServiceSucceeded(msg, ptoPopup, DatixWCF, myvar);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed
});

function ServiceSucceeded(result, ptoPopup, DatixWCF, myvar) {
console.log("ServiceSucceeded: " + result);
```

}

I get execute code that I put on “OnServiceSucceed” while the wcf is steel working…

How can I make the wcf works ONLY synchronously?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Its not WCF, its ajax which is Async here, refer async=false here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add to your ajax post  `async: false`

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: jsonText,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        ServiceSucceeded(msg, ptoPopup, DatixWCF, myvar);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed
});
```

Comment: You are saying async: false, I believe.

Comment: Uppsss!! little mistake

Comment: No!, i mean sync.. i need that the wcf works sync... (althought it must work sync works async !!!

Comment: If i add " async:false," --> i Get this error: A request synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of the negative effects on the user experience. Further information http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: @S.A. of course you'll get that warning because sync call is not recommended because of user experience etc. If you have to "really" call that synchronously, don't mind that warning.

Comment: And that should be a warning, not an error as you said.

Comment: I get an error  --> "ServiceFailed" function is executing.

Comment: excuse me !!.. you are right.. It works!!, (I had made a change in endpoint). Thanks.!..